# Numbers on a Blackboard

Tags: combinatorics, algorithm, blackboard

You are given an empty blackboard. Once a minute, you are allowed to do one of the following:

- Write two $1$'s on the blackboard
- Erase two copies of a number, $n$, and replace them with $n-1$ and $n+1$.

Here is an example of six possible moves: 
$$
empty\to 1,1 \to 0,2\to 0,2,1,1\to 0,2,0,2\to 0,1,0,3\to -1,1,1,3\to\cdots
$$

> What's the shortest time it takes to write $100$ on the board?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortest amount of time it takes to write the number $100$ is

> $164275$ minutes. xnor has already described a process for reaching $100$ in $164275$ minutes, so here I will argue that it cannot be done faster.

---

I will need to following fact.

**Claim**: Let $k$ be a non-negative integer. If there has ever been an integer $n>k$ written on the board, then for any interval of $k+1$ consecutive positive integers less than or equal to $n$, there are at least $k$ integers from that interval currently written on the board.

The special case $k=1$ was observed by xnor (once a number has appeared, at least one of every pair of consecutive smaller numbers must always be on the board).

**Proof**: Induction on $k$. The base case $k=0$ is vacuously true.

Now, let $k$ be arbitrary, and assume the claim holds for $0,1,\ldots,k-1$. Suppose some integer $n>k$ has appeared on the blackboard at some point. Let $I=\{a+1,\ldots,a+k\}$ be a set of $k$ consecutive positive integers, with $a+k\leq n$. At some point in time $a+k$ must have been written on the board, and at that time there were at least $k$ numbers from $I$ written on the board: the integer $a+k$, along with $k-1$ integers from $\{a+1,\ldots,a+(k-1)\}$ (here we use the inductive hypothesis).

Given that $k$ integers on the board were in $I$ at some point, we can argue that $k$ integers on the board are in $I$ at all times. The only time that the number of integers on the board that are in $I$ decreases is when we replace two copies of $a+k$ by $a+k+1$ and $a+k-1$, or when we replace two copies of $a+1$ by $a$ and $a+2$. However, in the first case, there were already $k-1$ integers on the board from the interval $\{a+1,\ldots,a+k-1\}$ before the replacement (by the inductive hypothesis), so along with the new $a+k-1$, that makes a total of $k$ integers $I$. The second case is identical.
 **This completes the proof of the claim.**

---

Suppose $100$ is written on the blackboard. Then the blackboard must also contain: at least one number from $\{99,98\}$, at least two numbers from $\{99,98,97\}$, and so on, up through $98$ numbers from $\{99,98,\ldots,1\}$. This means that the smallest possible value for the sum of the squares of the numbers on the board is
$$
100^2+98^2+97^2+96^2+\ldots+1^2=328549.
$$
As xnor has explained, the sum of the squares of the integers on the blackboard increases by $2$ each minute, so the number of minutes required is at least
$$
\left\lceil\frac{328549}{2}\right\rceil=164275.
$$
This is what we needed to show.

Answer (score 11):

So far I have a lower bound of

> $85850$

and an upper bound of

> $164275$

---

For the upper bound, consider the following simple strategy:

- Ignore 0's
- If there's two $n$'s, change them to $n-1$ and $n+1$.
- Otherwise, create two 1's.

Let's keep ignoring 0's and pretend that we can add a single 1 for half a step. We argue that at any point, each number appears once, except at most one number appears twice. We need that invariant that whenever $n$ appears twice, $n-1$ does not appear. Then, when we replace $n,n$ with $n-1,n+1$, there's at most one $n-1$, at most two $n+1$'s, and no $n$'s appear, so the invariant is maintained.

The invariant is also maintained when we create a single $1$ because there are no pairs (remember we're ignoring 0's). In reality, when we create two ones, the invariant is maintained as long as we can ignore a single 1.

So, at the end when $100$ is created, there can be at most one of each number plus an extra 1. Moreover, there cannot be a double since we just acted on $99$ and there are not two $100$'s. And, there cannot be a 99. So, at most, the numbers $1$ through $100$ can appear, with no $99$ and an extra $1$.

By the invariant argument below, this end position correspond to [this number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28sum+from+1+to+100+of+n%5E2%29+%2B+1+-+99%5E2%29%2F+2) of steps:

> $164275$ steps.

---

First, a weak lower bound for the number of steps it takes is

> $5000 = 100^2 /2$

We look at the statistic

> the sum of squares of the numbers on the whiteboard

Each move, causes the statistic

> to increase by 2. Adding two 1's clearly does so. Replacing $n,n$ with $n-1,n+1$ changes the statistic as $(n+1)^2+(n-1)^2-n^2-n^2 = 2$.

This gives the lower bound because

> the statistic starts at 0 and must end at least at $100^2$ for the number 100 to be on the board.

However, this lower bound cannot be sharp because

> the number 100 cannot be left on the board alone. It must also appear with 98.

We can improve the lower bound to

> $85850$

by

> observing that after the blackboard contains one of $a,a+1$, that fact must be true from then on, since removing an $a$ creates an $a+1$ and removing an $a+1$ creates an $a$. Since every number must be created on the way to $100$, the minimum possible statistic at the end is $100^2 + 98^2 + ... + 2^2 + 0^2$, which is $171700$, so the number of required moves is at least half of that.

Comment: Damn, you were faster by a few minutes *and* got a much bigger lower bound than I did :-/